# Prolog Issue: Having Trouble With Variables (If I need them or not)

Tags: prolog

I am working on a final assignment for my class and I was wondering if someone could guide me in how to work with these two problems (C and D) I have left. This is what I have as of right now. I am not looking for the straight answer. Can someone just guide me with an example. I have done a and b of the assignment, which is find all children employed and names of families without children. Some utility functions were given to us so we don't have to define a child every time for example. Here is the example family tree data. It is long so i have attached just one family here.

```
family(
        person(melvin, brown, date(25,april,1950), unemployed),
        person(alice, brown, date(2,september,1967), works(hom, 78000)),
        [person(bill, brown, date(18,november,1990), unemployed),
         person(grace, brown, date(18,november,1990), works(ibm, 55000)),
         person(barbara, brown, date(18,november,1990), unemployed),
         person(walter, brown, date(3, october, 1996), unemployed)] ).
```

and these are the utlities defined for us:

```
del(X, [X|Tail], Tail).

del(X, [Y|Tail], [Y|Tail1]) :- del(X, Tail, Tail1). 

husband(X) :- family(X, _, _).

wife(X) :- family(_, X, _).

child(X) :- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children). 

exists(Person) :- husband(Person); wife(Person); child(Person).

dateofbirth(person(_, _, Date, _), Date).

salary(person(_, _, _, works(_, S) ), S).  % Salary of working person

salary(person(_, _, _, unemployed), 0). % Salary of unemployed
```

**Here is my work as of right now:**

(a) Names of families without children

`? - family(_, person(Name, Surname, _, _), [])`

(b) all employed children

`? – child(person(Name, Surname, _, works (_, _)))`

(c) names of families with employed wives and unemployed husbands

```
? – wife(person), 

family(_, person(Name, Surname, _, works (_, _)));

husband(person),

family(_, person(Name, Surname, _, unemployed)))
```

(d) all the children whose parents differ in age by at least 15 years

- I really don't know where to start with this. Cause I don't understand how you can minus two parents ages logically. I don't know if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Concerning (c) you should use uppercase for variables. this would be `wife(WifePerson)` otherwise your sub-query `wife(person)` can not succeed). Alternatively you can also write `wife(person(Name,Surname,_,_....)`. Having said that the predicate wife and husband are totally superfluous in your query. I personally would however prefer to write

```
family(Husband,Wive,_),Wive = person(_,_,_,works(_,_));false.
```

or wife respectively.

Concerning (d) there would be the fancy answer, which requires to write the parents age utilising the Peano axioms. This would have been a cool homework. The idea is that

```
nat(0). % zero is a natural number
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X). every successor of a natural number is a natural number
```

Now you can define subtract as

```
sub(nat(X),nat(0),nat(X)).
sub(nat(s(X),nat(s(Y),Result) :- sub(nat(X),nat(Y),Result)
```

but it seems the definition of the ages was done in a lazy way.
Hence you can utilise the infix predicate `is/2` and just write

```
  AgeDiff is X - Y.
```